# Generating special numbers

Tags: number-theory

Here are three numbers that are related to one another:  9841, 8591, 4800

How are these numbers related and how are they generated?

Answer (score 7):

They form a

> Pythagorean triple, i.e.  $9841^2 = 8591^2 + 4800^2$. When used as the lengths of the sides of a triangle, the triangle has a right angle.

The general formula is:

> The triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$ are of the form:
>  $$c=k(u^2+v^2) \\ b=2kuv \\ a=k(u^2-v^2)$$
>  Where $u,v$ are coprime and not both odd. Cases where $k=1$ are called primitive triples, and they are such that $a,b,c$ have no common factor.
>
>  This case is a primitive triple with $u=96$ and $v=25$.

Comment: Your answer is partially correct. How did you obtain the values u and v?

Comment: @VassilisParassidis After checking that there is no common factor (so $k=1$) I just used $c+a=2u^2$ and $c-a=2v^2$.

Comment: Actually, even when $u$ and $v$ are both odd or non-coprime, they will still be valid Pythagorean triples (although they may be non-primitive - having $\gcd(a,b,c)>1$ - even when $k=1$).

Comment: @trolley813 That's true, but unfortunately you cannot get all non-primitive triangles that way, so you have to put in the factor $k$, and then it is neater to ensure that is the only common factor between them.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis That's right, for example, without $k$ you cannot get a triple with $\gcd(a, b, c) $ being an odd non-square number (e.g. 3 or 7).

Comment: @Jaap Scherhuis. If you have the triplet c=424241  b=154880  a=394959 then how do you find the method of their formulation without using the value of the triplets?

Comment: @VassilisParassidis Both your triplets are generated from $u,v$ such that $u$ and $u+v$ are square numbers, but I don't see how that makes them extra special.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis The first step for primitive triplets is: Lets have two coprime positive integers m,k. One is odd and the other even, and m›k. From there there are two more steps to obtain the values you need to formulate the a,b,c. In the second triplet  m=5 and k=4. You have to do the rest. Good luck.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis The formula I gave in my answer will generate primitive Pythagorean triples for any values of $u,v$ which are coprime, one odd and one even, $u>v$ (and $k=1$). Every primitive Pythagorean triple can be generated that way and it generates nothing else. You will have to be explicit about what extra property your subset of Pythagorean primitive triples has that makes them special.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis. If m=7 and k=2 find a,b,c.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis You still have not clarified what makes the triplets special (only one of which is mentioned in your original question). Maybe this whole question should be closed for being too unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis. These triplets are special because are generated in a unique way. If you set Y=8mk and m^3-k=z then from y,k,z you obtain a,b,c.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis This seems very terribly “what am I thinking of?” more than an actual puzzle. There’s no clues toward the unique formulation you’ve described that would help a solver arrive at that particular pattern.  Puzzles should be forward solvable from their clues, not merely be verifiable once the solution is known. How, then, is this a puzzle?